# iphone app size smaller than screen

Tags: ios, iphone, screen, xcode6

I'm developing an app and have come against a strange issue I can't find the answer for - when testing the app on an iPhone 5 the whole app display window is shrunk down to what looks like a 3.5 size display (the top and bottom of the screen are black and even the status bar is pushed down). When I test the app on an iPhone 5s running iOS 8 it displays full screen as expected.

Also when testing in the iOS simulator for iphone 5, and 5s it displays as expected. I'm using xcode 6 for development.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you add an iPhone5 screen size SplashScreen?

Comment: Hi David, I've got a Launch Screen.xib setup - the strange thing is it works on an iphone5s but not on the iphone5 (which have the same screen resolution) - Would it have anything to do with one running ios 7 and the other 8? Thanks!

Comment: I think the .xib for launch screen works only for iOS8, for iOS7 you have to set the static splash screens for every size. Check out this: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/

Comment: Yep - all sounds obvious now you mention! Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to set splash screen for your app. Otherwise it will take 3.5 screen size.
Just set the splash screen and you will be done.

Comment: That was accidentally removed. Saved my day! Thanks.

Comment: This was interesting to find out. Is there any documentation on why the "LaunchScreen.storyboard" is needed to determine size of the Screen ?

Answer (score 4):

So from iOS8, you can use a .xib as your Launch image, but if you have to support past versions of iOS, you have to provide static SplashScreens.

- [here is a link](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/) about replacing the launch image with a .xib file

If you have to use static Launch images, you have to add every supported resolutions:

1. 320 x 480 - not retina iPhones
2. 640 x 960 - retina 3.5" iPhones
3. 640 x 1136 - retina 4" iPhones
4. 750 x 1334 - iPhone 6
5. 1242 x 2208 - iPhone 6 Plus

Answer (score 0):

use size class approach on any height and any width. Hope you will get your solution from the following link
http://captechconsulting.com/blog/tyler-tillage/ios-8-tutorial-series-auto-sizing-table-cells

Answer (score 0):

just clarify on the other answers, make sure you also set the 'Launch Image Source' under 'General' -> 'App Icon and Launch Images'

screen shots....

**...mine used to be....**

[image]

---

**...and i changed it to... (and set an image)**

[image]

---

**GLHF!**